# Google Auth using Token

Tags: android, google-account

I've an android application that needs to navigate to a google service webpage (say calendar). Because I already have a Auth Token (using Android Accounts manager), I want to skip user being redirected to web login. Would auto-login be possible using authtoken ? 
If yes, what is the exact Url with params

Comment: Have you found an acceptable answer? Please mark it if so.

Answer (score 1):

you would append ?auth= to the url. I don't know if that works with all google urls, but for google voice and a couple others i've seen it work.

Comment: i tried with ?auth, ?token, nothing seems to work. Im surprised there's no clear documentation on this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a cookie.

First do a GET on this URL with the auth token at the end:
http://.appspot.com/_ah/login?continue=/stats&auth=

Then extract the cookie from the response and add it to the HTTP headers of all subsequent requests.