# Google auth token usage

Tags: authentication, google-fusion-tables

I would like to use google fusion tables, for which I need to login first.
I do a http request and get the "auth" token as response.
But now I stuck and don't know how to use this token?
I could neither find any google docs on this nor this thread helped: [Google Auth using Token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3067780/google-auth-using-token)

Because adding the auth token to the url does not work.

Answer (score 1):

You use the authorization code to get an access_token.

This has useful information:

https://developers.google.com/usiontables/docs/articles/oauthfusiontables

You then send the access_token with your sql query.